# Are these malicious requests in my apache access log?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

So I noticed that my apache access log is filled with these :

```
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:45 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?session_to_unset=123&token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48&_SESSION[!bla]=%7Cxxx%7Ca%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3BO%3A10%3A%22PMA_Config%22%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22source%22%3Bs%3A46%3A%22%2Fvar%2Ftmp%2Fsess_8r1hlgbmtrh26f9fnhoor7p32dgfvcfc%22%3B%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:46 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48 HTTP/1.1" 200 8127 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:47 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?session_to_unset=123&token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48&_SESSION[!bla]=%7Cxxx%7Ca%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3BO%3A10%3A%22PMA_Config%22%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22source%22%3Bs%3A50%3A%22%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fphp%2Fsess_8r1hlgbmtrh26f9fnhoor7p32dgfvcfc%22%3B%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:47 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48 HTTP/1.1" 200 8127 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:48 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?session_to_unset=123&token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48&_SESSION[!bla]=%7Cxxx%7Ca%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3BO%3A10%3A%22PMA_Config%22%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22source%22%3Bs%3A51%3A%22%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fphp4%2Fsess_8r1hlgbmtrh26f9fnhoor7p32dgfvcfc%22%3B%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:48 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48 HTTP/1.1" 200 8127 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:49 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?session_to_unset=123&token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48&_SESSION[!bla]=%7Cxxx%7Ca%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3BO%3A10%3A%22PMA_Config%22%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22source%22%3Bs%3A51%3A%22%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fphp5%2Fsess_8r1hlgbmtrh26f9fnhoor7p32dgfvcfc%22%3B%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:50 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48 HTTP/1.1" 200 8127 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:50 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?session_to_unset=123&token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48&_SESSION[!bla]=%7Cxxx%7Ca%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3BO%3A10%3A%22PMA_Config%22%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22source%22%3Bs%3A58%3A%22%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fphp%2Fsession%2Fsess_8r1hlgbmtrh26f9fnhoor7p32dgfvcfc%22%3B%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:51 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48 HTTP/1.1" 200 8127 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:52 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?session_to_unset=123&token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48&_SESSION[!bla]=%7Cxxx%7Ca%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3BO%3A10%3A%22PMA_Config%22%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22source%22%3Bs%3A59%3A%22%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fphp4%2Fsession%2Fsess_8r1hlgbmtrh26f9fnhoor7p32dgfvcfc%22%3B%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:52 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48 HTTP/1.1" 200 8127 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:53 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?session_to_unset=123&token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48&_SESSION[!bla]=%7Cxxx%7Ca%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3BO%3A10%3A%22PMA_Config%22%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22source%22%3Bs%3A59%3A%22%2Fvar%2Flib%2Fphp5%2Fsession%2Fsess_8r1hlgbmtrh26f9fnhoor7p32dgfvcfc%22%3B%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:53 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48 HTTP/1.1" 200 8127 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:54 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?session_to_unset=123&token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48&_SESSION[!bla]=%7Cxxx%7Ca%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3BO%3A10%3A%22PMA_Config%22%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22source%22%3Bs%3A53%3A%22%2Fshared%2Fsessionssess_8r1hlgbmtrh26f9fnhoor7p32dgfvcfc%22%3B%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:55 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48 HTTP/1.1" 200 8127 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
180.179.206.84 - - [06/Feb/2013:14:35:55 -0500] "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php?session_to_unset=123&token=a58cd3820282165c43b7443e856c2f48&_SESSION[!bla]=%7Cxxx%7Ca%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3BO%3A10%3A%22PMA_Config%22%3A1%3A%7Bs%3A6%3A%22source%22%3Bs%3A55%3A%22%2Fvar%2Fphp_sessions%2Fsess_8r1hlgbmtrh26f9fnhoor7p32dgfvcfc%22%3B%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 210 "http://50.116.55.81/phpmyadmin/index.php/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; pl; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8"
```

It doesn't look like that address is really doing anything harmful, but it looks like they're trying to breach something. The IPs are coming from Italy and India of all places. Notice the User-agent is a way old version of Firefox (although I know that's easy to spoof). I noticed a constant 20kbps stream of inbound traffic to my personal site (which honestly never usually sees traffic. Was just curious if anyone had any insight or information on a specific attack they're trying to do here. I could ban the IPs, but there are a whole bunch coming from different locations so I feel it might be a bit futile.

Comment: Welcome to public IP space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any public server will see these attempts (and many, many more targeting other commonly installed software). They're automated, usually done from overseas/Tor/botnets, and there's enough people trying this that blocking IPs is essentially useless.

Yes, they're malicious, but no, they're not really worth getting fussed over.

These usually target ancient versions of things like phpMyAdmin, WordPress, Drupal, and other common tools with known vulnerabilities - keep your third-party code updated and you should be fine.